# Как вернуть javascript code из HttpHandler без обновления страницы?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Доброго времени суток. 
У меня такой вопрос.

На asp.net есть кнопка `HttpHandler`  в `PostBackUrl`

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" PostBackUrl ="/handler.axd?qsd=10" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Этот хендлер, по нажатию на кпопку, возвращает файл из базы данных. URL станицы при этом остается неизменным, к примеру `http://localhost:56278/Default`. Но есть случаи когда он не возвращает ничего и в этом случае URL становится вида `http://localhost:56278/handler.axd`. Как, в случае если возвращать нечего, вернуть что-то типа alert(); без обновления станицы и смены его URL?

Пример моего хендлера:

```
 public class Document: IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest Request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse Response = context.Response;

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=somefile.ext");
        Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
        Response.Write("<script type ='text/javascript'>alert('Error!');</script>");

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема не в том, что "нельзя вернуть javascript". Проблема в том, что браузер при вашей схеме работы его не ожидает.

Есть два варианта выполнения POST запроса:

1. обычный полноэкранный пост. Делается с помощью формы (`<form method='post'>`) и отправки ее на сервер скриптом или по нажатию на `<input type='submit'>`.

   - Если при этом от сервера пришел ответ `Content-Disposition` - то текущая страница остается жить, и результат сохраняется как файл.
   - Если без `Content-Disposition` - ответ считается успешным переходом, текущая страница выбрасывается содержимое ответа показывается в окне браузера, url окна меняется на тот, по которому был сделан запросю
2. AJAX - спецвызов из скрипта, раньше осуществлялся через объект XMLHttpRequest (добавленный Microsoft ради Outlook Web, раскрученный Google ради GMail), а до него - через хаки вроде download behavior. Сейчас - встроенными средствами браузера + оберток на них вида `$.post(url)`. Этот метод

   - всегда инициируется из `javascript`.
   - получает ответ от сервера в виде объекта JavaScript - практически, в виде строки.

Эту строку можно показать на странице, выполнить как скрипт (если в ней пришел алерт, например). Но выдать ее как скачиваемый файл в общем случае нельзя (можно в html 5 через fileSystem API).

У вас первый вариант. Как только запрос отправлен, "передумать" и поменять его на второй нельзя, тем более со стороны сервера. Максимум, что можно сделать в вашем случае - разделить метод на два:

- Первый вызывать через ajax и возвращать в нем json с действием - или "скачать файл + ссылку на второй метод", или "показать ошибку".
- Второй дергать полноэкранным постом и по нему всегда отдавать файл (он у вас уже есть). Если что-то пошло не так - падать.

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под "дергать полноэкранным постом" ? Обычный postback метод  на стороне сервера ? 
Именно так сейчас все и работает, просто местами есть хендлеры, а местами postback'и. И я думал привести все единому виду.

Comment: @koks_rs обычный полноэкранный пост - это form на клиенте и кнопка submit в ней (или отправка той же формы скриптом). Неважно, что обрабатывает этот POST на стороне сервера - постбек метод, хэндлер, mvc или вообще php. Важно что это не ajax, а просто отправка формы. И в ответ на него вообще ничего сделать нельзя - потому что с точки зрения браузера это переход с текущей страницы куда-то еще. И как только запрос ушел в сторону сервера - текущая страница перестает иметь к нему какое-либо отношение.

Comment: @koks_rs т.е. у вас "URL отстается неизменным" и страница остается видна не потому, что "страница загрузила файл". А потому что браузер получает в ответ файл, который он сохраняет на диск. А вместо старой страницы ему показать нечего, вот он на ней и остается. Было бы что - он бы точно так же с нее ушел. Это видно, например, в IE при ctrl+click на ссылку закачивания файла. Он открывает новый таб, бодро так собирается показать страницу - и тут же получает файл, передумывает, **закрывает таб** и начинает качать файл.

Comment: Спасибо за подробные разъяснения.